# elsarticle - same surname, different author, same year - why cite as a, b?

Tags: citing, natbib, elsarticle

By running this:

```
\documentclass[review, authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{filecontents}   
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Chen2021,
   author = {Chen, Jie and Lasfer, Meziane and Song, Wei and Zhou, Si},
   title = {Recession managers and mutual fund performance},
   journal = {Journal of Corporate Finance},
   volume = {69},
   pages = {102010},
   ISSN = {0929-1199},
   DOI = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcorpfin.2021.102010},
   url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0929119921001310},
   year = {2021}
}

@article{ChenCEO2021,
title = {{CEO} early-life disaster experience and stock price crash risk},
author = {Chen, Yangyang  and Fan, Qingliang and Yang, Xin and Zolotoy, Leon},
journal = {Journal of Corporate Finance},
volume = {68},
pages = {101928},
year = {2021},
issn = {0929-1199},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcorpfin.2021.101928},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0929119921000493}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\citet{ChenCEO2021} \\\\

\citet{Chen2021} \\\\
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Why do different authors show a, b? Since authors in these two citations are not one person, is it possible to display the citation without a and b?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you primarily interested in obtaining an answer to your *why* question, or are you mainly interested in obtaining a suggestion for how to display the citation call-outs as "J. Chan et al (2021)" and "Y. Chan et al (2021)", respectively? Please advise.

Comment: Thanks, Mico. I'd like to display the citation call-outs as "J. Chan et al (2021)" and "Y. Chan et al (2021)", respectively. Since the authors are not one person, is it possible to display as "Chan et al (2021)" and "Chan et al (2021)", respectively

Comment: Apparently the style does not have a feature to disambiguate people by adding first name initials in citations (as in *J. Chan* vs *Y. Chan*). The style only uses the last name. But in order to have unambiguous citation labels it needs to do something and that something is adding the letter. You can't have Chan et al. 2021 and Chan et al. 2021 referring to two different works. Theoretically it is possible to change the style to use first names for disambiguation, but that would involve quite a lot of modification ...

Comment: ... Plus `elsarticle-harv` is a publisher style. Changing the behaviour of a publisher style is not really recommended as the standing assumption is that the style does what the publisher wants it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @moewe has pointed out in a comment, the `elsarticle-harv` bib style does *not* take first names into account when creating authoryear-style citation call-outs. Given that the publisher (Elsevier) seems to be ok with this setup, I don't think you have to worry too much about this outcome not being acceptable -- to the publisher, at least.

I realize that the following analogy may not be perfect, but I'm fairly sure that most readers of a paper won't take very long to realize that `Smith (2021a)` and `Smith (2021b)` need *not* have been co-authored by one and the same person. Same for `Kim (2022a)` and `Kim (2022b)`, `Wang (2019a)` and `Wang (2019b)`, etc. Hence, your readers may also not take all that long to figure out that `Chen et al. (2021a)` and `Chen et al. (2021b)` may, in fact, have been co-authored by two different persons whose surname happens to be "Chen".

However, if you think that it's absolutely essential to make sure that no confusion can arise as to which person named "Chen" stands behind a given citation call-out, I suggest you proceed as follows:

- In the bib entries, replace `Chen, Jie` and `Chen, Yangyang` with `{Chen, J.}` and `{Chen, Y.}`, respectively. *The curly braces are important.*
- In the document preamble, add the instructions

  ```
  \defcitealias{Chen2021}{J. Chen et~al.\ (2021)}
  \defcitealias{ChenCEO2021}{Y. Chen et~al.\ (2021)}
  ```
- In the body of the document, replace all instances of `\citet{Chen2021}` and `\citet{ChenCEO2021}` with `\citetalias{Chen2021}` and `\citetalias{ChenCEO2021}`, respectively.

If you go down this route, and if the bibliography contains yet another piece published by a "Chen" in, say, 2018, you should probably make similar adjustments for that piece as well.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}   

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{Chen2021,
   author  = {{Chen, J.} and Lasfer, Meziane and Song, Wei and Zhou, Si},
   title   = {Recession managers and mutual fund performance},
   journal = {Journal of Corporate Finance},
   volume  = {69},
   pages   = {102010},
   ISSN    = {0929-1199},
   DOI     = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcorpfin.2021.102010},
   url     = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0929119921001310},
   year    = {2021}
}
@article{ChenCEO2021,
   title   = {{CEO} early-life disaster experience and stock price crash risk},
   author  = {{Chen, Y.} and Fan, Qingliang and Yang, Xin and Zolotoy, Leon},
   journal = {Journal of Corporate Finance},
   volume  = {68},
   pages   = {101928},
   year    = {2021},
   issn    = {0929-1199},
   doi     = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcorpfin.2021.101928},
   url     = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0929119921000493}
}
\end{filecontents}

\defcitealias{Chen2021}{J. Chen et~al.\ (2021)}
\defcitealias{ChenCEO2021}{Y. Chen et~al.\ (2021)}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}

\usepackage{xurl} % allow arbitrary line breaks in long URL strings

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citetalias{Chen2021}; \citetalias{ChenCEO2021}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```